# Iterm on top of all windows?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

Is there a possibility for Iterm to always be on top?

I have seen some issues but don't know whether it's already implemented.

[Issue 2640 in iterm2: Always on Top function](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-issues/w3TuGF7ftgE)